# how to upload video on youtube using php from video url

Tags: php, youtube-api

```
<?php
$videoPath = "http://test.com/Uploads/UserProfile/test.mp4";
$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("Test title");
$snippet->setDescription("Test description");
$snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");
$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "public";
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client,$insertRequest,'video/*',null,true,$chunkSizeBytes);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($videoPath, "r");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
     }
fclose($handle);
```

this code return error like

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://test.com/Uploads/UserProfile/test.mp4 in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Youtube_Demo\test.php on line 114
>
> A service error occurred: Error calling PUT
> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos? //herepart=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UpagkMMJT7D1QCKY//l0GqdzlQFOMm6esWmtbuL0qjsbx4Sj1lekLD-LigsawnHVIKDlfugtl5nukaJ-PzbXAEBO7lx794A: //(400) Failed to parse Content-Range header.

Comment: Ok so which is line 114 in the 22 lines of code you show us?